# I get a warning that the entry type of one my cites “isn’t style-file defined”

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

```
(no line number):
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=35307, hash_size=35307, hash_prime=30011
The top-level auxiliary file: Semester.aux
The style file: alpha.bst
Database file #1: bibio.bib.bib
Warning--entry type for "Teknologikatalog" isn't style-file defined
--line 2 of file bibio.bib.bib
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 9 of file bibio.bib.bib
 :
```

This is what i wrote in my bibliography

```
@misc{Teknologikatalog,
    Author = "Teknologikatalog",
    Title = "Energistyrelsen",
    howpublished = {\url{https://ens.dk/service/fremskrivninger-analyser-modeller/teknologikataloger},
    {Sidst set 09/11-2016}}
```

Comment: The `alpha.bst` style file doesn't define `online`; use `@misc`. By the way, you should use `\bibliography{bibio}`, not `\bibliography{bibio.bib}`; as far as I know, only MiKTeX is tolerant about the extension being given.

Comment: It gives me the same warning

Comment: What are you actually using here? Bibtex or biblatex (if bibtex then font tag this as biblatex) and as egreg says `@online` is not defined outside biblatex so change it into say `@mich`. If you still get errors, then please update stating that error.

Comment: In my case the warning was triggered by accidentally prefixing the entry with two `@`s.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Do provide a `year` field. That way, you'll get properly-formed citation call-out labels.
- Using the entry type `@online` does no harm, but also little good, since it (a) isn't defined in the `alpha` bibliography style and (b) thus automatically gets treated as an entry of type `@misc`, which is the "catch-all" or "default" entry type. The use of the entry type `@online`, by the way, is the trigger for the warning message

  ```
  Warning--entry type for "Teknologikatalog" isn't style-file defined
  ```
- I'd use the `note` field instead of the `howpublished` field for the URL and the date the website was last visited. That way, the year-related information will come *before* the URL.
- Don't include the ".bib" extension in the argument of `\bibliography`. I.e., write `\bibliography{biblio}`, *not* `\bibliography{biblio.bib}`.

An MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@online{Teknologikatalog,
    Author = "Teknologikatalog",
    Title  = "Energistyrelsen",
    note   = {\url{https://ens.dk/service/fremskrivninger-analyser-modeller/teknologikataloger}, Sidst set 09/11/2016},
    year   = 2016,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel} % just a hunch...
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\begin{document}
\cite{Teknologikatalog}
\bibliography{biblio} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The same comment for `online` is true for `software` (which was my issue, changing it to `misc` worked).